# require file from another path in Lua

Tags: lua, path, require

The problem is that i cant find the lua file to use.

the filesystem looks like this:

```
`|-- plugin
    '|-- functions 
        ' -- helpers.lua
 |-- tests
    '|-- integration
    '|-- unit 
        ' -- unittest.lua
`
```

in unittest.lua i want to use the helpers.lua like this

```
package.path = package.path .. ';functions/?.lua'
require('helpers')
```

but there comes always an error 'no file'. I think the package.path is wrong. How can i use the helpers.lua script inside the unittest.lua script?

Comment: you should just need to add a bit more to the path to get it to work: `../../plugins/functions/?.lua`

Comment: The 'functions' folder as you specified is relative, so you need to know the working directory. I guess you would need either ';plugin/functions/?.lua' (if main script running in parent of plugin) or ';../../plugin/functions/?.lua' if running from unittest directly

Answer (score 1):

usually I have a main file in the same folder as where the other two folders are located.

first make a file named `mainfile.lua` (you don't have to name it that)

then try typing this code in `mainfile.lua` (you don't have to name it that):

```
require("tests/unit/unittest")
require("plugin/functions/helpers")
```

the folder system should look like this:

```
`|-- new folder
    `|-- plugin
        `|-- functions
            `|-- helpers.lua
    `|-- tests
        `|-- integration
        `|-- unit
            `|-- unittest.lua
    `|-- mainfile.lua
```

this works for me, not sure if it will work for you.
hopefully this helps!

Comment: While that works fine for globals, you will need to require in other files if you want to use locals. And unittests should not need to depend on the whole main too.